# 0:0 score in basketball

Tags: trivia, basketball, records, scoring

0:0 is quite common score in football (soccer), it also happens in other sports. Is it possible in basketball? In other words does it ever happen in official game? If not what was the closest result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When we are talking about professional basketball this result isn't realistic.

**NBA:**
On November 22, 1950, the Fort Wayne Pistons defeated the Minneapolis Lakers 19-18 in the lowest scoring game in NBA history.

This was prior to shot clock being added in 1954/55.

The lowest scoring NBA game since adding the shot-clock was in 1955, when Boston won Milwaukee 62:57 (119 points together).

The lowest score by one team was in 1999 Chicago vs. Miami when Chicago scored only 49 points.